# How do i enable scrollbar in highcharts in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, highcharts

I'm working with react Highcharts stacked column chart

I couldn't add scroll bar for column chart .In this example it have plotting applied values but not showing scroll bar.In my case it not happening.the view port is taking it own height and width even if i applied style to its parent.not fitting inside container

```
containerProps={{ style: { width: '100%', height: '100%' } }}
```

this also not working

[image: not fitting in its container]

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-blackburn-171dz?file=/src/App.js)

i'm stuck in this scroll bar issue when the api response coming with 100 more data the view port of react highchart is limiting to 24 data.I could not add scroll bar.

When i enabled navigator i can see the data but chart column is not plotting .please help

Comment: Hi @Dev, Everything seems to work fine in your example. Could you check it and describe the problem more precisely?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to close the issue .I have fixed with some googling .Thanks anyway @ppotaczek :-)

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-blackburn-171dz?file=/src/App.js

Fixed by removed xAxis  category

```
type:"category"
```